# Content type custom document information panel

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a custom content type with custom fields. I'm trying to create a custom document information panel using infopath. Whenever I try to do that infopath gives me this error

propertySchema0.xsd#/schema/element[1][@name = 'properties']/complexType[1]/sequence[1]/element[1][@name = 'documentManagement']/complexType[1]/all[1]/element[1]
Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'ns1'.

Any one have seen this before? 
There's nothing unusual about the fields in the content type, other than that their names are in unicode characters, could that be the problem?

### Update:

Ok, so the unicode characters in the display names have nothing to do with the error. The columns I'm using are pretty standard columns, mainly text, integer and boolean type columns. 
Anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

---

Ok, so the unicode characters in the display names has nothing to do with the error. The columns I'm using are pretty standard columns, mainly text, integer and boolean type columns. 
Anyone has any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured this one out. The SourceID needs to be set inn the field type definition in the feature manifest. Setting SourceID to the same value as the builtin fields dows the trick. Like this  SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sharpeoint/v3"

Comment: In my case I had to add SourceID and StaticName attributes to the field

Comment: I'm having the same problem and don't know where the feature manifest is? Where did you modify the file?